# Find root of function of 2 variables, with one variable set to constant

Tags: python-2.7, math, scipy

I have a function which is explicitly a function of two variables - however in practice, one variable is always set to a constant. For a very simplified version of my function, consider

```
def twovarfunc(x,z):
     return (x**2) - 2 - z
```

where, if I wanted to graph this function, it would always be of the form `func(x=np.linspace(),z=const)`. In fact, though, I don't actually care about what this function looks like - I just need to find the x-zeroes of this function given a value (or really, a range of values) of z.

I have already had success with, e.g.:

```
from scipy import optimize as opt   
def onevarfunc(x):
     return x**2 - 4
opt.bisect(onevarfunc,0,5)
```

Which returns a decimal that is very close to 2: 1.9999999999998863

My problem is that I don't understand the syntax necessary to tell Python that I want to specify the constant value of the second argument of the function while solving for the roots of the first variable. Unfortunately, I have not found the SciPy documentation helpful in this regard.

I have made a few attempts at finding the right syntax using modules like `optimize.minimize`, `optimize.root`, `optimize.fsolve`, but I haven't been able to get it.

I am very new to Python (and OOP in general) - my prior experience is in MATLAB, Igor Pro, and Mathematica. It's possible (probable?) that there is a very simple solution that I'm not seeing.

For the physics-inclined folks here, I am trying to find a variational solution of a function of which `twovarfunc(x,z)` is the derivative with respect to x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If z is constant, just treat it as a constant. `x**2 - 2 - z` becomes `x**2 - (2 + z)` where `2 + z` is constant, so just solve that.

---

Clarification in response to comment:

```
def twovarfunc(x, z):
    return x**2 - 2 - z

def solve_twovarfunc(z, low, high):
    # Find root between low and high for some value of z
    def onevarfunc(x):
        return twovarfunc(x, z)
    return opt.bisect(onevarfunc, low, high)
```

Essentially we define a new univariate function in `x` based on some constant value of `z`, then find its roots.

Comment: Do you mean saying `def func(x): x**2 - 2 - z`? If I define `z` elsewhere in the script as a constant (or, ideally, a linspace of its own), the function will "pull" the value(s) of z as a global variable? Like I said, I'm new to python, and I'm porting this code from Mathematica where all variables need to be explicitly passed into the function, whether they're set as constants or not.

Comment: This solution worked great, thank you! I knew there was a simple solution that I was overlooking... However I ran into an odd quirk - my script contains the function definition followed by `opt.bisect(testfunc,0,5)`. However when I run the script, there is no output. I must then go to the console and type the exact same thing: `opt.bisect(testfunc,0,5)`. Is there any reason why the script does not produce output, while retyping the last line of the script in the console gives me the output I want?

Comment: Are you actually calling the function? It won't do anything until you call it.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't define the root-finding operation as a part of a function. The entirety of my script is: `from scipy import optimize as opt // b=2 // def testfunc(x): // return x**2 - 2 - b // opt.bisect(testfunc,0,5)` (I used // for line breaks). When I run any script, all I'm doing is passing each line sequentially into the console, no? Is there a reason why `opt.bisect(testfunc,0,5)` yields output when I run it in the IPython console but not when it is written that way in the script itself?

Comment: I see ... you were simply running the `bisect` function, so it printed the return value in interactive mode. Just replace that with a call like `solve_twovarfunc(2, 0, 5)` and it will run the same way. Or `solve_twovarfunc(z=2, low=0, high=5)` if you prefer.

Comment: Got it. Defining the solver as a function makes much more sense than running opt.bisect every time I wanted to find the zero. Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're looking for is a partially applied function; it's a way to take a function and stick some of the parameters in to make a new function. You can use the built-in `functools` module to do this. If you have some function like this:

```
def func(x, z):
    return x ** 2 - 2 * z
```

Then you can partially apply it to make a new function that only takes one parameter by using `functools.partial`:

```
partial_func = functools.partial(func, z=8)
```

Now `partial_func` is a new function that only takes one argument, and when you call it with that argument set it's equivalent to calling the original function with `z` set to `8`; both of these are equivalent:

```
res = partial_func(20)
res = func(20, 8)
```

So for your code, you would do:

```
onevarfunc = functools.partial(twovarfunc, z=20)
opt.bisect(onevarfunc,0,5)
```

And that would find a zero in `x` holding `z` to be 20.